# How to log every HTTP request on Java EE application (path, timestamp, username(if available)) to database

Tags: java, http, logging, jakarta-ee

How may I log every HTTP request on Java EE application (path, timestamp, username(if available)) to database?

Comment: Which app server are you using? Weblogic (and others, I'm sure) can do this as a standard feature.

Comment: I did not say the app server because I wanted a standard solution. The application should run on Tomcat and WebSphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a request filter for your application

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/RequestFilter.htm

in the filter log to whatever you want to.

You can use the [log4j JDBC Appender](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm) to log to a database

Comment: Did you ever got this filter working? It seems there is a class "ReqWrapper" missing.